# Hausdorff distance between two set of finite points

Tags: algorithms, hausdorff-distance

Assume we have two (finite) sets of points, $A:=\{a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\}$ and $B:=\{b_{1}, \ldots,b_{n}\}$ in the closed hypercube $[0,1]^{d}\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Somebody know an "efficient" method/procedure/algorithm to compute the Hausdorff distance between $A$ and $B$? As $n$ can be very large, it is not seem very suitable to compute the distance between each pair of points of $A$ and $B$.

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: you mean two finite sets of points in the title. My first thought was to partition the hypercube into pieces and look at each piece, but can't quite see what I want to do with that and how it might help. Perhaps the size/number of pieces depending on number of points

Comment: Yes, my first thought was as you say, but I feel that this make more difficult the problem. Thanks.